# How to add links to different language versions of WordPress

Tags: plugins, themes, code

How to create link for current page but in different subdomain (translation) in WP?

For example on https://domain.com/test_page link to https://uk.domain.com/test_page/ and https://pl.domain.com/test_page/

Comment: the specific kind of translation you're asking for is normally done with a plugin, or manually by hand with a multisite, sadly you can't ask for recommendations on this stack but there are several very well known popular and easy to find solutions for this. Writing a system from scratch will be very difficult/time consuming, and there are multiple ways to do it which means it will be difficult to write an answer as it will need to cover every single one, making it the size of a small book.

Comment: yes, but I need only find current ulr and change https://domain.com/test_page to https://uk.domain.com/test_page/. only show link to different translation.

Comment: do you already have translations? If so then you can solve this with server level redirects without touching WP at all

Comment: yes, but I need only to create links for Google to translated pages. this will speed up the process of scanning these pages.

Comment: oh, that's unrelated to what you've asked for, Google uses HTML header tags to discover alternative language versions of the current page, not subdomains. Note that in this context a link is a `<a>` tag

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions#html, whatever SEO stuff you've seen about using subdomains can be disregarded, Google says use a HTML tag/HTTP header. Also WP has no native translation support, so to figure out how to get the translation URLs in code you would have to ask in the community/support of the translation plugin you chose